# Mapping Color Codes To Int in Java

Tags: java, int, mapping, bluej

I'm trying to write a change color method in Java that accepts an int parameter and changes that color based on that int. Valid colors will be in the range 1 - 6 for the six colors. You may decide which number (1-6) maps to which color. If the value is not in this range, make the circle red.

I am trying to do this without the use of an array list, but I am unsure how. Any ideas?

I've tried:

```
 if(newColor == 1) {
     newColor = "yellow";
 }
```

And I get an error message saying 'incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int.'

I've also tried:

```
if(newColor == 1) {
     newColor.equals("yellow");
}
```

And I get an error message stating 'int cannot be dereferenced'.

Answer (score 1):

`1` is an `int` literal.  If the compiler allows you to test `newColor ==`, then that means newColor must be an `int` variable.  Being an `int` variable, it is only allowed to hold `int` values.

`"yellow"` is a `String` literal.  The compiler will not allow you to assign a `String` value to an `int` variable.  You may only assign `String` values to `String` variables.

You're going to need two variables:  One to hold the given `int` value, and one to hold the `String` result.

Other languages (e.g., Ruby) might let you do it differently, but if you're going to use Java, then you are going to have to work within the Java rules to solve your problem.